# How do I uninstall a DKMS package if I have deleted the dkms.conf file?

Tags: drivers, uninstall, dkms, displaylink

The package in question is evdi-1.6.0. It didn't work as expected (ASUS Zenscreen only displays garbage), so I thought it would be uninstalled if I removed the files in usr/src.

How do I recover from this? `dkms status` only complains that the .conf file does not exist. I can not install other evdi-drivers as long as this package is installed.

```
sudo ./displaylink-driver-5.2.14.run 
Verifying archive integrity...  100%   All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 5.2.14  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 5.2.14 install script called: install
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 19.04
WARNING: Version 1.6.0 of EVDI kernel module is already running.
Please uninstall all other versions of DisplayLink Linux Software before attempting to install.
Installation terminated.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it working. What I had to do was to restart, install the new driver, and disable paging as described [here](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1181623-displaylink-ubuntu-driver-after-recent-x-upgrades). After that, one more reboot fixed it! Now I can use the monitor!